# .Net 4.0 latest web service technology?

Tags: web-services, .net-4.0

I was just wondering what is the most modern/easiest/best practice was to create a web service using the .Net framework, Im preferrably looking for a solution where it will be easy to enable multiple requests formats and data return types, particulary JSON and XML.

Any sugestions?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Have you looked into WCF Services ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)

Answer (score 1):

'best' in what way? The standard preferred .NET platform for inter-application communication is WCF.

Comment: Don't really know what I meant by 'best', I guess I just wanted to see peoples opinions on what they though was best for the job. thanks